# How to make redirection from one URL to another URL in apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

How to make redirection from one URL to another URL in apache? 
In file httpd.conf..

I need to make the following:
- User opens site "server.com"
- User automatically is redirected to "app.server.com"

How I can make it?

Answer (score 0):

in .htacces file enter this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^server\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.server.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is important that in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^server\.com$ [NC]` you keep the `\.` and don't replace it with `.` because `\.` is an escaped dot.

Comment: what is .htacces file? I have only httpd.conf

Comment: .htaccess file is a file that is interpreted by the http server.
create in a file name `.htaccess` in your webroot, when the client tries to load anything in the same folder or a subfolder of the same folder as a .htaccess it will read the .htaccess first.

if you create a file named `.htaccess` on your webroot and make sure that it contains this:

    `RewriteEngine on`

    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^server\.com$ [NC]`

    `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.server.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

if will redirect all clients from server.com to app.server.com